# Hibernate: How to cascade unmapped entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**Is it possible to set cascade without mapping one to many relationships?**

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECORD")
public class Record  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER")
    private User user;

    ...
}
```

If I try to delete a user and there exists any record of that user it obviously fails because of the foreign key. I would like to delete all of the user's records before deleting the user.
I see two options:

1. Map `Record`s as `@OneToMany` relationship in `User` and set `cascade`.

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
   private Set<Record> records;
   ```
2. Delete them manually before deleting user

Is there any third option, how to set cascade without mapping records in the user entity?